# A Tricky Double Sum

Tags: calculus, summation, zeta-functions

I was trying to solve an integral, which ended up being a difficult double sum.
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+n+1}}{k(k+2n)^2} $$
I tried to use symmetry, but in vain. The inner sum is similar to the alternating Hurwitz-Zeta function. Using it, I ended up with
$$ \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\zeta^{*}\Big(2,\frac{k+2}{2}\Big) $$
How can I solve this sum?

Answer (score 1):

$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+n+1}}{k(k+2n)^2}=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{16k}\left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{k+4}{4}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{k+2}{4}\right)\right)$$ I do not know how to compute the outer sum but it seems to converge quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{k=1}^{p} S_k \\
 10 & -0.0677739 \\
 20 & -0.0679219 \\
 30 & -0.0679398 \\
 40 & -0.0679445 \\
 50 & -0.0679462 \\
 60 & -0.0679470 \\
 70 & -0.0679474 \\
 80 & -0.0679476 \\
 90 & -0.0679477 \\
 100 & -0.0679478
\end{array}
\right)$$

The result is in the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p} S_k =a_p+b_p \,C + c_p\,\pi^2$$

Using the inverse symbolic calculator the result is close to $-\frac{11+10 \sqrt{11}}{65} $

Comment: Well, I knew that it can be represented in the form of digamma function and its fast convergence. But I didn't had an approximation. Thanks.