# A problematic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the integral

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$$
This is a part of one of the solutions of my previous posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4184955/931957). The user who posted this hasn't visited the site from over a month, so I thought it would be better to ask it as a post instead of a comment on the original solution.

The OP suggests to using a parameter. So I tried doing that.
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x\ln(1+ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx$$
Differentiating
$$\begin{align}I'(a)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(1+ax)(x^2+1)}\,dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{(x^2+1)(ax+1)}\,dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(ax+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{(ax+1)(x^2+1)}-\frac{x\ln x}{(x+a)(x^2+1)}\,dx\\&=\frac1{a^2+1}\int_0^1\frac{a^2\ln x}{ax+1}-\frac{2ax\ln x}{x^2+1}+\frac{a\ln x}{x+a}\,dx\\I'(a)&=\frac{\pi^2a}{24(a^2+1)}+\frac1{a^2+1}\int_0^1\frac{a^2\ln x}{ax+1}+\frac{a\ln x}{x+a}\,dx\end{align}$$
Now integrating from $0$ to $1$,
$$\begin{align}I&=\frac{\pi^2}{48}\ln 2+\int_0^1\ln x\int_0^1\frac{a^2}{(a^2+1)(ax+1)}+\frac a{(x+a)(a^2+1)}\,da\,dx\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{48}\ln2+\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\int_0^1\frac{2ax}{a^2+1}+\frac1{ax+1}-\frac x{a+x}\,da\,dx\\I&=\frac{\pi^2}{48}\ln2+\ln2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{x^2+1}\,dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2x}{x^2+1}\,dx\end{align}$$
Now solving the first and last integral and using the already proved relation
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx=-\frac34\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
we get
$$I=-2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx-\frac9{16}\zeta(3)$$
This doesn't help as this is what I was solving for in the first place.
Is there a better way to solve for $I$? Or maybe there is some possible manipulation in my solution that can potentially give a closed form.

Any help would be welcomed. Please also check the original post for further clarification.

**Probably the final edit:**

I've found that if we represent my last two integrals after differentiation using dilogarithm and use the identity $$\text{Li}_2(z)+\text{Li}_2(z^{-1})=-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\ln^2(-z)}2$$ we can easily solve it. No need to do manipulations using double integrals.

Comment: Alternatively, one can also compute the Mellin transform $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4} \csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ln(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{8} \sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}\csc\left(\pi s\right)\left(\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(1-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)$$ and differentiate with respect to $s$ and take $s\to 0$.

Comment: @KStarGamer: Thanks for the suggestion. How can we compute the Mellin transform? The integral looks dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feyman's trick seems a good suggestion. If we define
$$ I(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)\log(1+ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx $$
we have

$$ I'(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x^2)(1+a x)}\,dx = -\frac{a(\pi^2+4\log^2(a))}{8(a^2+1)}\tag{1}$$
by partial fraction decomposition and standard integrals. Indeed
$$ I'(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x^2)(1+a x)}\,dx + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-x\log(x)}{(1+x^2)(x+a)}\,dx \tag{1b}$$
by splitting the integration range as $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$ and performing the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ on the second part. This gives two integrals which are perfectly manageable through termwise integration of power series.

$I(0)=0$, hence

$$ I(1) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)\log(1+x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx = -\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{a(\pi^2+4\log^2(a))}{a^2+1}\,da \tag{2}$$

$$ I(1) = -\frac{\pi^2}{16}\log(2) -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{a\log^2(a)}{1+a^2}\,da = \boxed{-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\log(2)-\frac{3}{32}\zeta(3)\,}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: Please give the calculations after differentiating as that's exactly what I'm struggling with. The bounds from $0$ to $\infty$ is what is causing problems due to potential divergence of the integrals.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari: all right, I will expand $(1)$.